# Azure maps, show all search results as clusters

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, azure-maps

I noticed that when I show the results on the map, and if you have clustering enabled, you receive two types of shapes.

- **Clusters**
- **Features ( On my case Persons )**

I want to show all results as a list of persons, even when they are clustering.

The Map:

[Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2zGv.png)

As you can see we have on 1 Cluster with  2 person. The reason is because on the data we have 2 shapes, the cluster feature and the person Feature.

To Achieve this goal we have done the next,

On Moveend event we store on 2 separated arrays the persons and the clusters:

```
   var clusters = [];
   var persons = [];
   data.forEach(function (shape) {
        if (typeof shape.properties !== "undefined") {
            if (shape.properties.cluster) {
                clusters.push(shape.properties);
            }
        } else if (typeof shape.properties === "undefined") {
            properties = shape.getProperties();
            persons.push(properties);
        }
    });
```

On the Persons array we have the information of the persons, but on the clusters array we have only the information of the cluster, so we iterate on this array to get every person of the array as follows,

```
         if (clusters.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < clusters.length; i++) {
                datasource.getClusterLeaves(clusters[i].cluster_id).then(function (children) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
                        children.forEach(function (personProps) {
                            persons.push(personProps.properties);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

And i build the cluster layer as follows,

```
var clusterBubbleLayer = new atlas.layer.BubbleLayer(datasource, null, {
                radius: 15,
                color: '#007faa',
                strokeColor: 'white',
                strokeWidth: 2
            });

            map.layers.add(clusterBubbleLayer);

            var clusterLabelLayer = new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
                iconOptions: {
                    image: 'none',
                    font: ['SegoeUi-Bold'],
                    anchor: 'center',
                    allowOverlap: true,
                    ignorePlacement: true
                },
                textOptions: {
                    textField: '{point_count_abbreviated}',
                    size: 12,
                    font: ['StandardFont-Bold'],
                    offset: [0, 0.4],
                    color: 'white'
                }
            });

            map.layers.add(clusterLabelLayer);
```

But I want to know if there is another method to show all records of the maps as clusters even when there is only one person?

Many Thanks!

**Solution 1:**

I found what i think is a good solution using a "sequential execution" of promises,

Now I have a Promises Array so every use of method getClusterLeaves returns a promise and i store that response on the array,

```
   var persons = [];
   var promises = [];
    data.forEach(function (shape) {
        if (typeof shape.properties !== "undefined") {
            if (shape.properties.cluster) {
                promises.push(datasource.getClusterLeaves(shape.properties.cluster_id, 9999999, 0).then((e) => {
                    e.forEach(function (result) {
                        properties = result.properties;
                        persons.push(properties);
                    });
                }));
            }
        }
    });
```

And then i get the persons,

```
var buildPerson = new Promise(resolve => {
            data.forEach(function (shape) {
                if (typeof shape.properties === "undefined") {
                    properties = shape.getProperties();
                    persons.push(properties);
                }
            });
            resolve("solved");
        });
```

And Finally i show all the results when all promises of cluster function it's done,

```
 function runSerial() {
        Promise.all(promises)
            .then(buildPerson)
            .then(function () {
                persons.forEach(function (person) {
                    BuildHtml(person);
                });
                displayNext();
            });
    }
    runSerial();
```

And it works Good :)

Comment: That looks like the correct approach.